# How to debug why the compiler crashes on my C++ program?

Tags: c++, arrays

Code 1: supposed to take a matrix (m by n) size and then find the min value in each row. Doesn't show any errors, runs but the black screen (devc++) for the compiler simply crashes without doing anything and has a ridiculously high return value (3221225725 to be exact).

I'm not sure how to fix or improve it, also it works when the size of the matrix is constant, like instead of cin to get size a simple number makes it work. I am not sure why; I'm new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int m,n;

    int B[m][n];

    int A[m+1][n+1] = {0};

    cin>>m;

    cin>>n;

    for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y)
        {
        cout<< "Enter in value for row " << x << ", column " << y << ".\n";

        cin>>  A[x][y];
        }
    }

    cout << "Input:" <<endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y)
        {
        cout<< A[x][y] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y)
        {
            A[x][4] = A[x][1];

            if (A[x][4] > A[x][y])

                A[x][4] = A[x][y];
        }
    }

    cout <<"Output:"<<endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < m+1; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < n+1; ++y)
        {
        cout << A[x][y] << "\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    getchar ();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is code 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i,j,R,C,Too;
    double a[i][j];
    float f;
    Too=0;
    cin>>R;
    cin>>C;
    for (int i=0; i<R; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            f=i+j/2;
            a[i][j]=sin(f);
            if (a[i][j]>0)
            {
                Too=Too+1;

            }
        cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
        cout << a[i][j]<< endl;
        }
    cout<<Too<<" Shirheg eyreg element bn"<<endl;

}
```

the elements in this matrix is generated by the formula  f=i+j/2; a[i][j]=sin(f);
and simply outputs how many positive elements are there. for some odd reason the elements are always double like the output is something like:
0
0
0.841471
0.841471
and one other number then gets getting double and then a number and then double.
how to fix?

Comment: My suggestion would be to first try to understand what each line is doing. The computer is only doing what you tell it to do. Getting a program to run when we're first learning to program is mostly about making sure we told it to do the right thing.

Comment: Your original title told readers that (1) your code does not work, (2) you are not sure why, and (3) you would like some help. All of those things are rather obvious, and readers are not left with any useful information to help them understand quickly what help you need (and whether they might be able to help). Please get into the habit of writing useful and detailed titles - it will help you in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange return values and crashes when working in C++ are often a sign of uninitialized values. For example, consider the following:

```
int main() {
 int m,n; // <-- declare 'm' and 'n', but we don't initialize them to have a value
 int B[m][n]; // <-- use the values in 'm' and 'n' to allocate memory for 'B'
 ...
 cin >> m; // <-- only now are you setting m to a value, but you already used it.
 cin >> n; // <-- same thing with n.
 ...
}
```

The above code is wrong because it uses the variables identified by 'm' and 'n' before it sets them to have a particular value, so until you set their value (with cin) they just have whatever value happened to be sitting in memory at the time they were created.

Assigning a value to them is called "initialization" or initializing them the first time you do it. Before that they just hold that value from memory.

Ultimately, each line of code is using some variables and may be making assignments to other variables. So make sure each variable that is being *used* has already been initialized before you reach that line of code.

You will have to debug your own code in order to learn effectively, and the above example is not the only error or issue here, but a few basic tips to help you along the way:

- Always look out for anything using uninitialized values like m and n
- If it makes sense, initialize values as soon as they are created
- i and j and k as variable names are usually declared only in a loop, because you usually only need them to exist inside the loop.
- If you declare `int i` in a function, you should not declare `int i` in a loop within that function. The two i's now mean different things, which is confusing.
- put spaces around your `<<` and `>>` operators. It will make the code easier to read.
- If you're having trouble, try printing out the value of a variable with cout and see if it makes sense. If not, there is a problem before that point in the program.
- If you're having trouble, try working on one section of the code at a time until it behaves the way you expect.

Comment: i see, thank you for the tips, i'll get back to you as soon as i fix my code :)

Comment: scratch that, i did try your tips and it indeed helped the code run, but is there a way to fix this? f=i+j/2;
            a[i][j]=sin(f); the output it keeps showing isn't really what a sin function does. T.T

Comment: You mean it's not giving you sin(i + (j/2))? Break it down. Is j/2 giving the value you expect? is i+j/2 the value you expect? Is sin(i+(j/2)) the value you expect? Once you know where your expectation differs from what the computer does, you can learn more about that particular thing. For example, if you discovered the sin function was the problem, look up the sin function in documentation and if that still doesn't help try using the sin function with simple values like 0 and pi over 2, to see if it behaves.